# How to copy files from one drive to another while maintaining folder structure

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I used an old program (rich copy) to copy files from one drive to another. The files have been created, as well as the directory structure, but due to some long file names and directory names some files were not copied over.  The destination drive is already in live production, so I don't want to rerun the copy command.

I exported all of the files not copied onto an excel list.  For each line, I want to copy from the source drive (S: drive) to a local (D:\share)

Sample of the list of source files:

S:\directory_abc\department2\file1.txt

S:\directory_abc\department3\version 2\file2.txt

I want the files to go into the following folders (folders already created by Rich Copy):

D:\share\directory_abc\department2\file1.txt

D:\share\directory_abc\department3\version 2\file2.txt

How would I go about doing this using PowerShell?  Thank you.

Comment: Use robocopy and don't bother with file lists.

Comment: You can try my script which I created for backing up my Steam Games and adapt it for your need. It keeps the folder structure. https://gist.github.com/swbbl/59f8825da3272b57c4a439fb50227f9a